# XOOM: Disable HDMI Output

Tags: xoom

In our application, we need to disable HDMI output, we have been using HDMI status API (http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/motorola-hdmi-status-api/ ) successfully on few devices.

In Xoom, this API is NOT supported. Is there any other way we can detect HDMI and disable it on Xoom.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Mohan

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to disable HDMI on Xoom. I was only able to get the information if the HDMI out is connected.